# Do splines preserve monotonicity?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, interpolation, splines

Start with a monotone nonincreasing function and sample it at finite set of points $x_0, ..., x_n$, $x_i<x_{i+1}$ so that $f(x_i)<f(x_{i+1})$. If you approximate $f$ with a linear spline then the resulting piecewise-linear approximation will certainly preserve monotonicity.

The question is: if you approximate $f$ with [natural cubic spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)#Algorithm_for_computing_natural_cubic_splines) will monotonicity be preserved as well?

Comment: No, they don't. If you must have monotonicity, have a look at e.g. [Fristch-Carlson](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0717021) or [Steffen](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1990A%26A...239..443S). Those are $C^1$ interpolations, however.

Comment: But have a look at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation   or  https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1177012761  ...

Comment: @gmvh don't hesitate, if you add the new tag [tag:splines], to also add (virtual) top-level tags when they're missing, such as [tag:real-analysis] or [tag:na.numerical-analysis]. ([Link to chat room: "MO editors lounge"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10243/mo-editors-lounge))

Comment: @YCor: thanks for the hint. I'll do so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you mean nondecreasing, i.e., monotonically increasing. If so, the answer is "no." For example, interpolate (0,0), (1,10) and (2,11) with a natural cubic spline:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not only is the answer "no", but for any number $N$ you can construct a monotone function and sample it such that the natural spline approximation will have $N$ extremum points.

See the figure (and its enlargement) below for an example.
A full explanation of this function can be found [in this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/308365/123142).

[image]
[image]